# Firebase Messaging causes crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

The app installs and works the first time it's installed from the IDE, but after doing some changes in the code, the second install crashes immediately with the following message:

> Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
> Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib '@rpath/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging' not found for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16B1A2D5-B6AC-4952-95D2-D054E16F59ED/appName.app/appName', tried but didn't find: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16B1A2D5-B6AC-4952-95D2-D054E16F59ED/appName.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging' '@rpath/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging' '/System/Library/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging'
> Highlighted by Thread: 0

I'm using the following packages:

> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging.4.1.1.1
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics.6.0.4
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core.6.1.0.1
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks.4.0.1
>
> Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID.4.2.1
>
> Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds.7.47.0.1

I've tried on multiple physical devices and also simulators - all crashed in the second install.

What I've tried:

1. Updating the libraries to the latest version.
2. Deleting Obj, Bin and XBD folders.
3. Cleaning the solution and rebuild.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

Environment

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.6.1 (build 26)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 13.18.1.31 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: Hi , could you explain more about  *"after doing some changes"* , this will be helpful to check where problem is .

Comment: Change anything in the code (adding a space for example), just so it will compile again, and not install immediately.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.6.1 (build 26) 

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 13.18.1.31

Comment: That's strange . Whether this project created on this Mac or moved from another computer ?

Comment: The project was created on this mac, not moved.

Comment: The only thing that seems to work is downgrading VS, Xamarin.iOS sdk and Xcode.

Comment: If so , you can update this as answer . Later find better solution we also can update here   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to fix this is downgrading VS, Xamarin.iOS SDK and Xcode. After the downgrade I was also able to use the latest version of the libraries.